# Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied ROLLBACK 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

Im trying to upload an image on s3 bucket using ruby on rails and paperclip, but its not working I have tried almost everything on the web.

**I know there is many questions about this but I have tried most of them, and nothing worked please review the question cause i listed what i tried in the question**

I did set IAM User and User has AmazonS3FullAccess policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I did set policy on the bucket

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1557294263403",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1557294241958",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::726051891502:user/borroup-admin"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::borroup",
            "arn:aws:s3:::borroup/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

I did set CORS configuration editor on the bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I made sure all the Public access settings for this bucket set to false

[image]

This is ruby on rails config

Note: im using the user access_key_id and secret_access_key for this

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    path: ':class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
    s3_host_name: 's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials:{
      bucket:'borroup',
      access_key_id: '************',
      secret_access_key:'***************************',
      s3_region:'us-east-2'
  }
}
```

I do get this error when I try to upload the image
[image]

```
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied in PhotosController#create
```

When I check the bucket log I get this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are the bucket and IAM user in different account ?
If so, the bucket policy is incorrect, the correct bucket policy

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1557294263403",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1557294241958",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::726051891502:user/borroup-admin"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::borroup","arn:aws:s3:::borroup/*"]
      }
    ]
 }

// --> borroup/asterisk --> for some reason, asterisk symbol removed here or maybe I don't know how to use stackoverflow correctly.

If the User and bucket in the same account, the policy doesn't matter because IAM user has full permission.

Comment: I updated my resource to "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::borroup", "arn:aws:s3:::borroup/*" ] but still not working